# Text mode install for Linux Mint

Tags: linux, installation, linux-mint

I've downloaded the ISO for Linux Mint Live Install (Qiana), and I don't see any option for text-mode install.

The installer menu which appears on boot basically has (1) Install and (2) Install in Compatibility Mode, but I don't see any option to install in text mode.

The installer does provide the ability to edit the configuration of each option (by pressing Tab) which allows you to manually edit the install flags.  But, Googling around I cannot find any flag which instructs the installer to use text mode instead of graphical mode.

Is there any way to install Linux Mint in text mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it doesn't.

Source:  Comment 28 of [this](http://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=2594) Linux Mint blog entry